# How to create identity column using GUI?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I want to add identity column while creating a table. I know how to do it using a SQL statement, but how can I do the same in GUI?

Comment: Which UI?  SSMS?

Comment: sorry, i don't understand your question. can you provide more detailed information?

Comment: GUI means? SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Use script for all,It is best practice.Don't use GUI

Comment: If you know how to do it via T-SQL, why would you want to go back to using the GUI and slow yourself down?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) in "Column Properties"/"Identity specification" just set "**(Is Identity)**" to "Yes".

Here you can also:

- set the increment with "Identity Increment"
- chose the initial value with "Identity Seed"

[image]

According to Microsoft Docs (more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/table-column-properties-sql-server-management-studio)):

> - **Is Identity** Indicates whether or not this column is an identity column. To edit this property, click its value, expand the drop-down
>     list, and choose another value.
> - **Identity Increment** Displays the increment value specified during the creation of this identity column. This value is the increment that
>     will be added to the Identity Seed for each subsequent row. If you
>     leave this cell blank, the value 1 will be assigned by default. To
>     edit this property, type the new value directly.
> - **Identity Seed** Displays the seed value specified during the creation of this identity column. This value is assigned to the first
>     row in the table. If you leave this cell blank, the value 1 will be
>     assigned by default. To edit this property, type the new value
>     directly.